# Раскадровка видео в Qt Creator

Tags: qt

подскажите, пожалуйста. Как можно сделать раскадровку видео в Qt? Необходимо, чтобы сохранялся каждый кадр. Заранее, спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

есть классное приложение ffmpeg, можете использовать межпроцессно, можете пощелкать исходный код. Написано на с++, работает очень круто. Не советую даже копать в сторону QMediaPlayer, потому что работает он так себе, много мороки с кодеками, да и скорость не очень, как по мне. Так что сюда:

[офСайт](https://ffmpeg.org/)

Например этот код сохраняет сет кадров в нужную папку

```
ffmpeg -i file.mpg -r 1/1 $filename%03d.bmp
```

или более подходящий

```
ffmpeg -i input_file.mp4 -ss 01:23:45 -vframes 1 output.jpg
```

где

```
-i input file           входной файл
-ss 01:23:45            время кадра
-vframes 1              1 кадр
output.jpg              выходной файл(любое расширение картинки)
```